# If the word is in two columns then priority in the results in mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a table like these:

menu_id  menu_name           menu_description
[image: menus table]

i would like to order the results giving a priority if the word is in the menu_name and menu description. How can i achieve this?

UPDATE:
with this query i get the most relevant results on top:

```
    select menu_id, menu_name, menu_description from ( select menu_id, 
    menu_name, menu_description, case when menu_name like '%salame%' 
    then 1 else 0 end + case when menu_description like '%salame%' 
    then 1 else 0 end as order_value from z8upvan6w_menus) as t order 
    by order_value desc
```

results:

```
    menu_id | menu_name              | menu_description
    13      | Panino Salame e Noci   | Salame, Noci, Caprino e Insalata
    14      | Piadina Salame e Noci  | Salame, Noci, Caprino e Insalata
    11      | Panino Caprese         | Mozzarella, Pomodoro e Insalata
    12      | Panino Boscaiolo       | Speck, Brie e Salsa Boscaiola
```

my question is why the third and fourth record appear if there is no word "salame" in any field, how do i get rid of them?

Comment: What word?  What is the `menu_name`?  What is the "menu description"?

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: Because the records are only ordered, not filtered. I'll update this in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you can use a dynamic numeric order with value 1 when the name is in the menu_name and 1 when the name is in menu_description. Sum them up when you select and order the results by the summed up value.
Like this:

It's written according to the SQL Server syntax, but I think you should be able to convert it the way you want.

UPDATE: Adding where clause to the query below to filter out the records which don't match both the menu_name and menu_description.

Assuming @input_val is the value you're trying to find in the columns.

```
select menu_id, menu_name, menu_description
from (
 select menu_id, menu_name, menu_description, 
 case 
    when menu_name like '%' + @input_val + '%' then 1
    else 0
 end
    +
 case
    when menu_description like '%' + @input_val + '%' then 1
    else 0
 end
 as order_value
 from menu_table) as t
 where t.order_value > 0
 order by order_value desc, menu_name asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not filtering out any records.  For that, you need a `where` clause:

```
select menu_id, menu_name, menu_description
from from z8upvan6w_menus
where (menu_name like '%salame%') or
      (menu_description like '%salame%' )
order by ( (menu_name like '%salame%') +
           (menu_description like '%salame%')
         ) desc;
```

Notes:

- The `where` clause does the filtering.
- No subquery is necessary.  You can order by an expression.
- I revised the expression so it uses the fact the MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.